# On Area 51, spoilers reveal the text

Tags: bug, area-51, spoilers

On Area 51, when you have a spoiler, you can see the text underneath.

[image: Screenshot before revealin the spoiler]

Text:

[image: Screenshot of a revealed spoiler]